# Drupal cron error: failed to open stream

Tags: php, drupal, cron

I've set up my Drupal 7 cron job like so:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/myaccount/public_html/cron.php`

However, cron sends me an email with the following error message:

> Warning: include_once(/home/myaccount/includes/bootstrap.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myaccount/public_html/cron.php on line 13
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/myaccount/includes/bootstrap.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/myaccount/public_html/cron.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_bootstrap() in /home/tente myaccount studios/public_html/cron.php on line 14

It appears that cron is somehow stripping out `public_html` from the path.  I uploaded a temporary PHP file and printed out `getcwd()` and it reports the path correctly, including `public_html`.  So somewhere between line 11 when `DRUPAL_ROOT` is defined as `getcwd()` and line 13 when the include is called, something strips out `public_html` from the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use curl to call your webserver so that the correct php.ini and openbasedir directives are set. See https://www.drupal.org/cron

Comment: Huh, I guess I never realized that Drupal had added automatic cron.  No need to schedule it through cPanel, I guess.  Thanks!